# How to Send a Message from Handheld to Android Wear in Background

Tags: wear-os

I'm a new bee working on Android Wear and seeking some help on achieving what i want from my app.
step-1) Since Android Wear doesn't have luxury of WiFi yet, i am pushing some request from my wear to HandHeld.
step-2) My app on Handheld,receives the request perfectly and make server contact to get the json reply.
step-3) Now i need to send this json reply to my Android Wear but in Background.

i.e I will have a dummy app on handheld and never has a UI for user interaction, i just use it as an intermediate to communicate with server on behalf of Wear.

I'm facing problem while sending the server response to Wear in BACKGROUND(step-3).

If anyone has tried something like this, i am all ears!!

(In simple words, i don't want any app to run on handheld but do server calls for me in background and send it back to wear)

Answer (score 0):

Android Wear does support wifi, so I am not sure what you meant by your first statement. Secondly, you do have an app on the wear side running to begin with (the one that is making the request in Step 1) so why isn't that enough to receive the response to the request it had sent? In fact, that is the right approach for your app; it makes a request and should handle the response that it receives.

Comment: Thanks Ali, I'm using Android 5.1.1 -android-wear emulator. Does emulator support Wifi?? if it is, can my app on wear be completely independent of mobile app??? i believe, since i can't install apps on wear, we need to install it on handheld first which in turn pushes the same on to the wear.

Comment: I've read this " You cannot send http request directly from watch. Fetch internet data from the phone, then transfer it to watch with Data Layer API. " lines often here.

Comment: I don't know whether the emulator supports wifi or not; never tried it. Regarding wifi, assuming that your watch supports that and it is turned on, when your watch is disconnected fro the phone, then the wifi on watch behaves as it should; you can use it to make calls on the network (and internet, if your network has access to internet). When your watch is connected to your phone, that is no longer the case, that is why it is best not to solely rely on wifi and instead use the connected phone to communicate with the network.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Wear emulator does support WiFi, and handles https requests.

Unfortunately real Wear devices do not except in special circumstances - I think you need to Enable wifi, Connect to a network, AND turn off bluetooth (on phone or wear or both I'm not sure).
This is surprisingly annoying when developing using 3rd party code that makes http requests as you don't find out it doesn't work until you try it out for real.

On the other hand - I did see a class called WearHttpHelper.java in https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WearCompanionLibrary, though I've never used it.